# Validate Input to a C Program

Tags: c, validation

i have a c program in which i am accepting 2 numbers as input.
How do i validate if input entered is numbers only and not characters.

```
void main()
{
  int a,b;
  printf("Enter two numbers :");
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
  printf("Number 1 is : %d \n Number 2 is : %d",a,b);
}
```

[Edit] Added Sample Code

Comment: The code will be as long as it needs to be.

Comment: question edited and there need not be a limit.

Comment: Depends on the manner you are planning to accept the input

Comment: I have posted Sample Code,Please have a look

Answer (score 3):

Besides the other interesting suggestions (especially the one with `scanf`), you might also want to use the [isdigit](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html) function:

> The isdigit() function shall test
>   whether c is a character of class
>   digit in the program's current locale

note that this function examines only ONE char, not an entire bunch of them.

It is always good practice to resort to already-built functions; there are intricacies you might not be aware of even in the simplest task, and this will make you a good programmer overall.

Of course, in due time you might want to look at how that function works to get a good grasp of the underlying logic.

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that `isdigit` only works on individual characters, not entire strings, so this would require testing input character-by-character.

Comment: @dreamlax yes, I should have pointed it out better. Have edited the question accordingy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` returns the number of items that it has successfully scanned. If you asked for two integers with `%d%d`, and `scanf` returns 2, then it successfully scanned both numbers. Any number less than two indicates that `scanf` was unable to scan two numbers.

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    int result;

    printf("Enter two numbers :");
    result = scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    if (result == 2)
    {
        printf("Number 1 is : %d \n Number 2 is : %d",a,b);
    }
    else if (result == 1)
    {
        // scanf only managed to scan something into "a", but not "b"
        printf("Number 1 is : %d \n Number 2 is invalid.\n", a);
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
        // scanf could not scan any number at all, both "a" and "b" are invalid.
        printf("scanf was not able to scan the input for numbers.");
    }
}
```

One other value that `scanf` may return is `EOF`. It may return this if there is an error reading from the stream.

Also note that `main` returns `int`, but you have it declared with `void` return.

Answer (score 1):

Read user line of text input as a *string*.  This greatly simplifies error handling.

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
char buf[100];

for (;;) {
  printf("Enter two integers :");
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    printf("Input closed\n");
    break;
  }
```

Then test the string for 2 `int`s with no following junk.  Use `sscanf()` (simple) , `strtol()` (more robust), etc.

```
  int n;        // %n records where scanning stopped
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d%d %n", &a, &b, &n) == 2 && buf[n] == '\0') {
    printf("Number 1 is : %d \n Number 2 is : %d", a, b);
    break;
  }
  printf("<%s> is not 2 integers.  Try again\n", buf);
}
```

---

More advanced code uses `strtol()` to validate and also detect excessively long lines of input.